# Spectral measure of a self-adjoint operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm dealing with a proof of a theorem that was left for the reader (not a news sadly). 
The proposition states the following : 
 Let A be a self-adjoint operator and $\{\mu_n\}_{n=1}^{N}$ a family of spectral measures. Then 
$$\sigma(A)=supp\{\mu_n\}_{n=1}^{N}$$ It's quite easy to show that $supp\{\mu_n\}\subseteq\sigma(A)$, thanks to the spectral theorem. But I have problems showing the other way. The idea I had was to prove that $(supp\{\mu_n\})^c\subseteq\rho(A)$ but I don't know what else to do. 
 I'm open to any other idea, not necessarily the solution. 
 Thanks you for the consideration and sorry for my bad English.